# What is this seed pod and heartwood, maybe Ash?

Tags: identification, trees, seeds

I am working on a wooden staff from a fallen branch. I am pretty sure it is a variety of Ash tree but I am not sure which. As it is still very early spring there are no buds or leaves to examine, just the seed pods left from last year, the bark (thick and rough) and the heartwood that I have revealed on my staff.

Currently I am thinking either White Ash, Black Ash or European Ash, but would love a pro's thoughts.

*Click on pictures for larger view.*

[image: branch] [image: seed pod]

Answer (score 2):

What's your location?  That definitely looks like an ash samara.  I'm leaning towards a white ash because the samara doesn't look like a black ash's for sure.  I'm not as familiar with European Ash, but based on the fact that white ash is way more common in the U.S. than European ash, it's probably safe to say that walking stick is white ash.